# Get one digit after decimal point iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, double, decimal

I am trying to get one digit after decimal and store it as double. 
For eg : -

```
float A = 146.908295;
 NSString * string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.01f",A]; // op 146.9
  double B = [string doubleValue]; // op 146.900000
```

i want output as 146.9 in double or float form..,before duplicating or downvoting make sure the answer to this output is given..
Thanks

**Edited:-**

```
  NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.01f",currentAngle];

    tempCurrentAngle = [str doubleValue];;

    tempCurrentAngle = tempCurrentAngle - 135.0;

    if (tempCurrentAngle == 8.7) {
        NSLog(@"DONE ");
    }
```

here currentAngle is coming from continueTrackingWithTouch method, which will be in float..here it does not enter in if loop even when tempCurrentAngle value changes to 8.700000 .

Comment: Mathematically `146.9` and `146.900000` are same! then why you need `146.9` ? Because when you need to display this value then you have to convert in string and then you can show decimal that you want!!

Comment: i need to implement math and compare it further...

Comment: if you will compare `146.9 and 146.900000` then it will equal!

Comment: check edited ques

Comment: I am not getting your question! you said it will not enter in `if` clause, why ?

Comment: as you said that 146.9 and 146.900000 will be equal..,but above in edited code when this situation takes place it does not hit if clause...why ? that i am unable to figure out

Comment: I got your issue! I am posting answer! Wait

Answer (score 1):

You can compare string values instead of double like,

```
 double currentAngle = 143.7;   // I have taken static values for demo. 
double tempCurrentAngle = 0.0;

NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.01f",currentAngle];

tempCurrentAngle = [str doubleValue];;

tempCurrentAngle = tempCurrentAngle - 135.0;

NSString *strToCompare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.01f",tempCurrentAngle];

if ([strToCompare isEqualToString:@"8.7"] ) {

    NSLog(@"DONE ");
}
```

If you debug once line by line then you will get idea that why it was not entering in `if caluse`.

`tempCurrentAngle` get `143.69999999999999` when you convert `str` to `double` then you reduce `135.0` from it so it's value will be `8.6999999999999886` and then you compare it with `8.7` then it will definitely not being equal! but if you convert `tempCurrentAngle` string with one decimal point then it will be `8.7`! so you should compare string values instead of double!

Comment: i have tried this solution earlier it works but further for implementing math i need to convert that again in double

Comment: yeah then you have to do that! because you can not get double value in one decimal point!